# Java program reading indefinite amount of numbers from a user till a positive is entered

Tags: java, loops

I need to write a java program reading in an indefinite amount of numbers and saves them to a collection of numbers, until an (even number) is entered in by the user. I have tried with a while loop, that when a positive number is found in it it stops. But it is not really working. Here is codes I have tried:

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    int programInteger = 1;
    int inputtedInteger;
    
    while (programInteger < 2) {
    System.out.println("Enter a number: "); //Asks user to input a number
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    inputtedInteger = Scanner(in.nextLine);
    
    if (inputtedInteger != 0) {
        System.out.println("The number "+ inputtedInteger +" that you inputted is not an even number, try again: ");
        inputtedInteger=in.nextInt();
    }
    else if (inputtedInteger % 2 == 0){ 
        programInteger =+1;
        System.out.println("The number "+inputtedInteger+" that you entered is an even number!");
    }
    
}
    
}
/*  if(inputtedInteger % 2 == 0) {
        System.out.println("The number "+ inmatatTal +" you entered is an even number!");
    }
        else {
            System.out.println("Enter a number?! ");
            inputtedInteger = in.nextInt();
        
        }
```

Comment: there are many many issues with your code segment, I'll be honest. First, do not create a scanner inside the loop, but rather have it outside. Second, you are checking for parity of the entered number, not whether it is positive. And finally, your program is printing "number is not even" whenever 2 is input by the user, which is a logical mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixing a few things in the logic of the loop should work:

```
int inputtedInteger = 0;
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    
while (inputtedInteger < 1) {
    System.out.println("Enter a number: "); //Asks user to input a number
    inputtedInteger = in.nextInt();
    
    if (inputtedInteger % 2 != 0) {
        System.out.println("The number "+ inputtedInteger +" that you inputted is not an even number, try again: ");
    }
    else if (inputtedInteger % 2 == 0){ 
        System.out.println("The number "+inputtedInteger+" that you entered is an even number!");
    }
    
}
```

Comment: It is not working as a loop, meaning once I have entered a number like three that is uneven, it tells me its an uneven number and that I should try again, but when I try again, I am not able to enter a new number. Also where can I add close scanner?

Comment: After the while loop, outside of it.

Comment: Enter a number: 
1
The number 1 that you entered is not an even number, try again:                 I can not write a new number. I can only enter a number once. The application is supposed to let me enter a new number till an even number is entered.

Comment: Change the while condition to be while (inputtedInteger % 2 != 0). In your question you had said repeat until it is positive.

Comment: I changed the while condition to while (inputtedInt % 2 != 0) and now it does not work at all. I also tried with while (inputtedInt % 2 == 0) and I can only run the application for one time, meaning I can only enter a number once, so If I enter the number one, the console prints the number 1 you entered is not an even number, Try again;     and on this stage I am not able to enter a new number. How much I tap the number buttons.

Comment: Also change first line to int inputtedInteger = 1; so the condition doesn't immediately fail before taking input

Comment: Thank you! Now it worked after I changed int inputtedInt to 1 it finally works as it should! But still having problem with the scanner, I wrote Scan.close() outside the while loop after the else if bracket and are having an error in my application.

Comment: in.close() to close the scanner.

Comment: Thank you so much. It is working perfectly. I am a computer science student preparing for java exam, it have been a while I have been away from programming. But I am so thankful for all your help making it work. It is working smoothly now and I do not know how to thak you.

Answer (score 1):

I would setup an outline for the code like this:

```
setup Scanner, create collection
while true:
   userInput = scanner.nextInt()
   if userInput > 0: break
   collection.add(userInput)
print('user entered', collection.length(), 'numbers.')
```

Hope that helps. I'll leave you to fill this using actual Java syntax.
I wrote a comment on the OP on why your structure is failing to solve the issue at hand.

Comment: Thank you, you do not know a why to formulate it as a loop? basically asks you to enter numbers until you enter an even number that basically terminates the application?